# Mysterious Letter

Tags: cipher, steganography

My friend Niko sent me a letter the other day:

> I DONT HΑVE ANY TIME TO TALK. IVE BEEN FRΑMED FOR TREΑSON АND  M ON THE RUN. I NEED YOU TO HELP ME ESCAPE BАCK TO POLAND. I DO HАVE MY PASSPORT, BUT IT WONT DO ME ANY GOOD ΑS THINGS STАND. I HAVE MΑDE ΑRRАNGEMENTS WITH АN AMBАSS DOR TO LEΑVE U.S. SOIL THROUGH А CARGO SHIP BOUND FOR ARGENTINIА. I WONT SAY ITS N ME АS THIS LETTER MAY BE INTERCEPTED АLONG THE WΑY. I NEED YOUR HELP TO GET TO THE EMBАSSY SAFELY. I HАVE TOLD YOU ENOUGH FOR YOU TO WORK OUT THE LOCΑTION WHERE I NEED YOU TO MEET ME TOMORROW АFTERNOON. ΑT THIS POINT, ΑNYTHING MORE I WRITE WILL ONLY MАKE IT E SIER FOR THE FBI TO TRACK ME DOWN. THEREFORE, I WILL COUNT ON YOUR SUPPORT АND АWAIT OUR MEETING IN THE DESIGNATED PLΑCE. I WILL BE WEΑRING Α CARNΑTION IN MY LΑPEL, AND CARRYING MY RECORD COLLECTION.

I can't figure out where he wants me to meet him, however. Can someone work it out?

Comment: Is Argentin*i*a intentional? I mean, the typo?

Comment: The I has no significance to the solution of the puzzle. It was a typo, but not an intentional one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that

> the letter As aren't all the Latin letter that we're familiar with. Many of them are either the Greek alpha or the Cyrillic (Russian) A instead.

Interpreting those as

> ternary, with Greek being "1", Cyrillic being "2", and Latin being "0", then chunking them into groups of 3, ignoring extra letters, gives:
>
>   `INFRONTK FTOWNFRLJ?`, which I believe is supposed to be "IN FRONT OF TOWN".

Comment: Perhaps this has an obvious answer that I'm missing, but out of curiosity, how'd you notice that?

Comment: @puzzledPig Click edit on the question. You will see that even obvious words have red lines under them showing wrong spellings. Clearly, the A was different from the usual A. After that, it was all Deusovi.

Comment: @puzzledPig - Copy and paste it into your favorite word processor. (Or just click "edit".) You'll see that there are "misspelled word" marks underlining *half* of words. Those marks all end just before or start just after As, which means those should be inspected more. Copy-paste a few into the search bar and the results do *not* look to be in English for many of them.

Comment: Ah, thank you, @Sid and @Deusovi!  Good to know :)

Comment: I am accepting this solution is correct, as it is the correct solution for the text as I wrote it. I realize that I probably messed up an A here or there, leading to the original message being garbled. I am going to update the post with the intended text, but this will still be the accepted solution.